# how to implement calculation for dynamically formed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Dynamic Script :

```
SET @cols = stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ','+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt)) 
             FROM   Events
             WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
             ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
             FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
--Print @cols

SET @select_cols = stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Max('+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt))+') as '+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, t)) 
             FROM   Events
             WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
             ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
             FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
--Print @select_cols

Select @query = '

Select Name, tableName,'+@select_cols+'
        from (
SELECT      Name,
            tableName,
            Cnt
    FROM  Table1 l 

            WHERE Name=''Employee'' AND
                     Start_dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date))T
PIVOT (MAX(Cnt)FOR Start_dt IN ('+@cols+') )PVT
GROUP BY  Name, tableName
'

EXEC   (@query)
```

and getting output like this

```
 Name     TableName  [2017-07-10]   [2017-07-09]

 mohan     Employee    10020     10080
```

I want to implement calculation on counts of both date columns

```
    Name      TableName  [2017-07-10]   [2017-07-09]   Difference  Percentage

    mohan      Employee      10020          10080        60           0.6%
```

How I need to implement this calculation in this query.

percentage calculation in Static :

```
case when [2017-07-09] > [2017-07-10]
                then cast(round (([2017-07-09] - [2017-07-10]) *1. / [2017-07-09] * 100, 2) as decimal(3,1)) 
                else 0
           end as [%]
```

How to add this calculation in dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more query to get @diff_cols as below

```
declare @diff_cols varchar(max)

Set @diff_Cols = stuff((SELECT  '-Max('+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt))+') '
             FROM   Events
             WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
             group by Start_dt
             ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
             FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
```

And modify your dynamic query as below:

```
Select @query = '

Select Name, tableName,'+@select_cols+', Difference = '+@diff_cols+', [Percentage] =    case when QuoteName(ParseName(replace(@cols,'','',''.''),2)) > QuoteName(ParseName(replace(@cols,'','',''.''),1))
                then cast(round ((QuoteName(ParseName(replace(@cols,'','',''.''),2)) - QuoteName(ParseName(replace(@cols,'','',''.''),1))) *1. / QuoteName(ParseName(replace('[2017-07-10],[2017-07-09]','','',''.''),1))* 100, 2) as decimal(3,1)) 
                else 0
           end as [%]
        from (
SELECT      Name,
            tableName,
            Cnt
    FROM  Table1 l 

            WHERE Name=''Employee'' AND
                     Start_dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date))T
PIVOT (MAX(Cnt)FOR Start_dt IN ('+@cols+') )PVT
GROUP BY  Name, tableName
'

Select @query -- check your query and then execute as below
EXEC   (@query)
```

Comment: yeah i will check and let you know

Comment: but percentage is getting complicated @kanan i will post the percentage query suggest me how can i implement in Dynamic SQL

Comment: can you check the updated logic in static and suggest  me to how to implement in dynamic way

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Used ParseName to get first and second dates

Comment: Quick question: Why you are doing MAX? can you post the input and expected output... You might not require that MAX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148777/discussion-between-mohan111-and-kannan-kandasamy).

Comment: in the expected result I'm getting nulls that's why I have used MAX and more over these are not  the exact tables and the query

Comment: percentage logic is not all working if I'm printing the result it is giving something which is not related to requirement

Comment: this percentage is not parsed correctly for difference of the columns you have took MAX() but for percentage columns in you have took @cols how this going to give percentage

Comment: My question is max is not at all required why you are getting null values? Did you selected only required columns in sub query T?

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this (I didn't tested it)

```
    SET @cols = stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ','+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt)) 
                 FROM   Events
                 WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
                 ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
                 FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
    --Print @cols

    SET @select_cols = stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Max('+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt))+') as '+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, t)) 
                 FROM   Events
                 WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
                 ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
                 FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
    --Print @select_cols

/* --- line changed --- */
    Select @query = 'SELECT A.*' 
            +', ' + REPLACE(@cols,',','-')+' AS Difference' +', ('+ REPLACE(@cols,',','-') +')/'+SUBSTRING(@cols, CHARINDEX(@cols,',')-1)+' AS Percentage FROM ('
    +
    'Select Name, tableName,'+@select_cols+'
            from (
    SELECT      Name,
                tableName,
                Cnt
        FROM  Table1 l 

                WHERE Name=''Employee'' AND
                         Start_dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date))T
    PIVOT (MAX(Cnt)FOR Start_dt IN ('+@cols+') )PVT
    GROUP BY  Name, tableName
    ) A
    '

    EXEC   (@query)
```

Comment: I will check once

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 22
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function